# .htaccess - it is possible to hide all /#some from sample.com/#some

Tags: php, .htaccess

There's some way to hide all redirect from URL,
or maybe just show my domain on every click

I've tried to use this in .htaccess but the sample.com/#some is not gone just (.php) is hide.

```
RewriteEngine On
#remov php exten
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
#redirect root to sub
RewriteRule ^((?!).*) /%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!).*)/#{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash in the URL is client-side only. So it is not sent to the server, so you would never change it via .htaccess file.

However, you could use some javascript codes to remove it like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
removeHash();
});

function removeHash () { 
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('#')[0]
}
```

Do not forget to modify $('a') with your ids if you need. Currently the code above is removing all #somes when any link is clicked.

Updated:

Or you can completely prevent from page refresh incase you want to use onclick attribute of a element. In that case, use below function instead.

```
function removeHash () { 
window.location.hash='';
}
```